# cuDNN failing to initialize possible version mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I'm running the code below trying to train a bpr neural network.  I'm getting the error below.

"Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above."

from googling it seems to indicate that the cudNN isn't initializing, maybe because I have the wrong versions of tensorflow-gpu, cudNN, and cudatoolkit.  Can anyone tell me if my versions are correct or perhaps what else the issue might be and how to solve it?  the code was originally written for tensorflow 1.3 but I'm using python 3.6 and they appear to be incompatible. so I tried to use the lowest version I could get to run on 3.6.

tensorboard               1.15.0             pyhb230dea_0
tensorflow                1.15.0          gpu_py36h5a509aa_0
tensorflow-base           1.15.0          gpu_py36h9dcbed7_0
tensorflow-estimator      1.15.1             pyh2649769_0
tensorflow-gpu            1.15.0
cudatoolkit               10.0.130                      0    anaconda
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.0_0

code:

```
f=open('DVBPR.log','w')
config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False,allow_soft_placement=True)
sess=tf.Session(config=config)
sess.run(init)

t=[0]*numldprocess
for i in range(numldprocess):
    t[i] = threading.Thread(target=load_image_async)
    t[i].daemon=True
    t[i].start()

oneiteration = 0


for item in user_train: oneiteration+=len(user_train[item])

step = 1
saver = tf.train.Saver([k for k in tf.global_variables() if k.name.startswith('DVBPR')])

epoch=0
while step * batch_size <= training_epoch*oneiteration+1:

    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={keep_prob: dropout})
    
    print('Step#'+str(step)+' CNN update')

    if step*batch_size / oneiteration >epoch:
        epoch+=1
        saver.save(sess,'./DVBPR_auc_'+str(K)+'_'+str(step)+'.ckpt')
        auc_valid,auc_test=Evaluation(step)
        print('Epoch #'+str(epoch)+':'+str(auc_test)+' '+str(auc_valid)+'\n')
        f.write('Epoch #'+str(epoch)+':'+str(auc_test)+' '+str(auc_valid)+'\n')
        f.flush()
    
    step += 1
print("Optimization Finished!")
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
   1366     except errors.OpError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1349       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1350                                       target_list, run_metadata)
   1351 

~/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1442                                             fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1443                                             run_metadata)
   1444 

UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node DVBPR/Conv2D}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-4a27b3e61c3e> in <module>
     21 while step * batch_size <= training_epoch*oneiteration+1:
     22 
---> 23     sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={keep_prob: dropout})
     24 
     25     print('Step#'+str(step)+' CNN update')

~/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    954     try:
    955       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 956                          run_metadata_ptr)
    957       if run_metadata:
    958         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1178     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1179       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1180                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1181     else:
   1182       results = []

~/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1357     if handle is None:
   1358       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1359                            run_metadata)
   1360     else:
   1361       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

~/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1385 
   1386   def _extend_graph(self):

UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node DVBPR/Conv2D (defined at /home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]

Original stack trace for 'DVBPR/Conv2D':
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 664, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 612, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 149, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 442, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1462, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 690, in <lambda>
    lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 743, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 787, in inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 748, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
    yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
    yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 545, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin,
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 306, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2867, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2895, in _run_cell
    return runner(coro)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3072, in run_cell_async
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3263, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-14-e6fb5ccc089e>", line 29, in <module>
    result1 = CNN(image1,dropout)
  File "<ipython-input-11-d043bee5e9ec>", line 13, in CNN
    conv1 = conv2d(x, Weights('wc1'), Biases('bc1'), strides=4)
  File "<ipython-input-10-cdb0788297c6>", line 4, in conv2d
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 2010, in conv2d
    name=name)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 1071, in conv2d
    data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/sb_dvbpr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

Comment: Did you look at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu ?

Comment: This error is because of version incompatibility. Install the correct CUDA toolkit and cuDNN for right NVIDIA driver. Also check Tensorflow-gpu support. Thanks!